# Why Does This <a href download> HTML Redirect to File Instead of Downloading?

Tags: html, download

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
    <a href = "img/test.txt" download> Download </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

This identifies the file that I am trying to download, but instead of downloading it like I expect the "download" attribute to do, it just redirects to the txt file within the browser. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Safari?

Comment: Chrome. @NikhilSingh

Comment: Man I do not see any issue with the code, you can try going with this https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

Comment: The given code is working perfectly fine for me on Chrome

Comment: Maybe I need to replicate this in a different environment then.

Comment: Yeah, I tested it on chrome and safari and it worked everywhere. Though it's just a hit and trial thing, try doing `ctrl + shift + R`

Comment: So just to be clear, you're getting a download prompt once clicked, right? Not a redirect to the file within the browser?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220652/discussion-between-nikhil-singh-and-matt-g).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you download the file, (React env, as you mentioned in the chat)

```js
import txtFile from '<path_to_txt_file>';

// putting this inside the React component
<a href={txtFile} download="txtFile.txt"> Download Here </a>;
```